# Google API for iphone to get a location is not working?

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps

Hello
I am using google api and this method to search a location, but now it's showing
(610,0,0,0) in response ??

Here is my code:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

double latitude = 0.0;
double longitude = 0.0;

if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
else {
     //Show error
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = latitude;
location.longitude = longitude;

return location;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ::

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
   double latitude = 0.0;
   double longitude = 0.0;

   NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];

   NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];

   NSDictionary    *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey:  @"results"];   // get the results dictionary
   NSDictionary   *geometryDict = [resultsDict valueForKey: @"geometry"];   // geometry dictionary within the  results dictionary
   NSDictionary   *locationDict = [geometryDict valueForKey: @"location"];   // location dictionary within the geometry dictionary

   NSArray *latArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lat"];
   NSString *latString = [latArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser

   NSArray *lngArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lng"];
   NSString *lngString = [lngArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser

   CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
   location.latitude = [latString doubleValue];// latitude;
   location.longitude = [lngString doubleValue]; //longitude;

   return location;
}
```

I found same issue earlier.

May be there is an issue regarding Google API Service.

Hopefully, it'll be htlp to you.

Thanks.

Comment: Good.. Pleasure to help you. Enjoy Coding..:)