# Google API gives error when location entering in Danish language setting in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, google-api

I am using a Google API to finding latitude longitude from Address location. And its working fine in English language settings. But when select Danish setting in Internationalization then it gives a server error from "Google". As I think there may be required to do localization in app but how?

[image: When language selected as Danish and response gives by Google API]

Comment: Do you have the response from Google? Would help to know what the error posted back was.

Comment: When google gives responce its hang in my network checks which gives me the error of "Srver not available". I tried to take device log its gives me nothing.

Comment: What are you using as the network connection, Apple's own methods or AFNetworking/some other networking stack?

Comment: I am using AFNEtworing , and its stuck when its check HTTPConncetion service reachebility in responding methods. Actually Goggle not understand that word which generate via dansk keyboard and responding in such way.

Comment: If you're using AFNetworking, then you should have a `id JSON` object in your success/failure blocks - can you log that and see what the response is? Also, the failure block should give you an `NSError` object as well which should help troubleshoot.  AFNetworking's reachability checks don't run on a per-request basis but rather monitors for reachability changes.  I'm guessing reachability passes but you end up in the failure block because it's a non-200 response, so do check out the JSON and error objects in the failure block.

Comment: Oh, also - supported languages: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1 and you can set the language parameter in your request using `language=da` (or `language=danish` try it out)

Comment: please check this question may be it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431767/google-api-for-iphone-to-get-a-location-is-not-working

Comment: @ArpitKumar give as … some code… how do you make the request?

Comment: Is it the Danish language setting that's causing the problem, or maybe just the ø character not being escaped properly in the request? Does entering that character from the English keyboard (tap-hold "o", select) cause the same problem, or not?

Comment: @Wildaker you caught things right there is problem due to that letter, it not appears in other places (dansk language).

Comment: @ArpitKumar, then my guess is that there's a problem with special characters not being escaped correctly, then messing up the network request. I'd look at that area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muhammad is giving the answer above, but I'll take the opportunity to explain what (I think) the issue is as well, as I had this issue in live production code a few weeks ago.

`NSURL` is flat out bad with unescaped strings with "special" content (e.g. UTF). First thing I'd do is check if the `NSURL` you get back is `nil`.

The way to do `NSURL` strings is to use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` before passing the string in.

This simple example demonstrates this:

```
NSString *string = @"http://test.com/teståäötest";

NSLog(@"url with string! %@", [NSURL URLWithString:string]);
NSLog(@"url with escaped string! %@", [NSURL URLWithString:
  [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]);
```

with output

```
url with string! (null)
url with escaped string! http://test.com/test%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6test
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about AFNetworking, but I would do it as below with Apple's NSURL.

Assume your URL is a string named "googlapiurl", your NSURL should be initiated as:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[googlapiurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Hope it helps.